# Open an Excel file using VBA in Outlook - Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I set Outlook to run the following script when an email is received from a specific email address.

I want to download the attachment then open an Excel file.

I get:

> Compile error: User-defined type not defined

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim source As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
    Dim ExWbk As Workbook
    Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
    
    saveFolder = "C:\Reports\Daily Traffic Report per Site\Source"
            
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Reports\Source\*.*"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next
        
    Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Reports\Calculation.xlsm")
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you included a reference to the excel object library in your Outlook VBA project?

Answer (score 1):

To use early binding, you first need to reference the available Outlook object library. To do this from Visual Basic (VB) or Visual Basic for Applications, follow these steps if you try to run the code in Outlook:

1. In the Visual Basic Editor, on the `Tools` menu, click `References`.
2. Click to select the `Microsoft Excel XX.0 Object Library` check box, and then click OK.